# Get the size of a repo in linux excluding specific sub-repo

Tags: linux

I am want to know the size of a repository in linux, excluding recusively all the subfolder that start with horizons:

I tried this command but i couldn't get the needed result:

```
find -type d -not -name "horizons*" -exec du -sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` has an option `--exclude=PATTERN`

```
du -sh repo --exclude 'horizons*'
```